# What are all the modes (scales) based on the major scale?

Tags: theory, scales, modes

I've heard that there are 7 different scales based on the major scale, like the minor scale, which is made by shifting the major scale pattern 6 to the right. What are the names of the other scales made by shifting the whole step pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean the "modes" of the major scale.

Starting on the first note of the major scale the mode names are...

- Ionian
- Dorian
- Phrygian
- Lydian
- Mixolydian
- Aeolian
- Locrian

With a scale of C major we can say something like *the second mode of C major scale is the D Dorian mode*.

As you described, you can get the modes of a major scale by permutating through it by moving up by steps. But another way to create modes is by adding sharps and flats to either a major or minor scale.

If you start with a C major scale and then add a flat on the ^7 tone to lower it, you will have the C Mixolydian mode. So, here is the list of modes again, with notes about those alterations.

- Ionian (same as major scale)
- Dorian (natural minor with a raised ^6 tone)
- Phrygian (natural minor with a lowered ^2 tone)
- Lydian (major with a raised ^4 tone)
- Mixolydian (major with a lowered ^7 tone)
- Aeolian (same as natural minor)
- Locrian (natural minor with lowered ^2 and ^5 tones)

Whether you permutate the major scale or lower/raise tones you will see that the sequence of whole steps and half steps is the same for each mode. In other words the whole/half step sequence is the same for the D Dorian mode of the C major scale and the C Dorian mode.

As a side comment...

It's true when you move up 6 or down 3 from the first note of the major scale (the tonic) you go the *relative minor*, or the *natural* minor scale, but keep in mind there are three inflections of the minor scale...

- natural minor
- harmonic minor (where the ^7 tone is raised a half step)
- melodic minor (where the ^6 and ^7 tones are raised by half step)

Comment: Or it could be said the melodic minor is the parallel major with a lowered third...But melodic has two incarnations - the classical, where ascending is different from descending, and jazz melodic, where it's the same up and down.

Comment: @Tim, I was tempted to answer that way: melodic minor is major with a lowered third. If figured that is the jazz conception (esp. because jazz uses modes of mel. minor.) But, I really dislike the 'classical' textbook asc/desc distinction with melodic minor. It simply isn't true. Direction doesn't make the distinction, but the prevailing harmony. If the harmony is dominant and the scale descends, raised ^6 and ^7 may be used. I think I'll post my own question re. the historic origin of the textbook description. I don't know what it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, the exam boards seem to have a different concept from ours! Harmonic is from the harmony angle, melodic is from the way the tune itself meanders, and fills that 3 semitone gap without the jarring the harmonic minor would produce.

Comment: So says the teaching. Anyway, I posted a new question https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/77060